# C# Fastest way to intersect lists of strings

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core

I am using `hashet`, **linq** `Intersect()` and `Count()` to find intersection of two lists of strings.

Code being used

```
private HashSet<string> Words { get; }

public Sentence(IEnumerable<string> words)
{
    Words = words.ToHashSet();
}

public int GetSameWordCount(Sentence sentence)
{
    return Words.Intersect(sentence.Words).Count();
}
```

Method `GetSameWordCount` is Taking > 90% of program runtime as there are milions of Sentences to compare with each other.

Is there any faster way to do this?

I am using **.net core 3.1.1 / C# 8** so any recent features can be used.

> **More info:**
>   Input data is coming from text file (e.g. book excerpt, articles from web).
>   Sentences are then unaccented, lowercased and split to words by whitespace >regex.
>   Short words (<3 length) are ignored.
>   I am creating groups of sentences which have N words in common and ordering >these groups by number of shared words.

Comment: I don't think you're getting the benefit of the HashSet's lookup time with Intersect. Maybe `return Sentence.Count(word => Words.Contains(word));`?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal / Why are you trying to do this? Also where is this data coming from?

Comment: ↑ The reason I ask is let's say this is data in a database. There could be a faster way to do this instead of pulling the data into memory and then doing what you are doing now. Example: in Sql Server you could use FTS which would be much more efficient. By knowing more about the problem we might be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: @Igor I have edited the question to add more info.
I do not mind loading the data to database first if it means faster processing.

Comment: @stkxchng Heh, I think you missed the point. If this would _come_ from a database, a query to _fetch_ the specific data would be much faster and more efficient than loading it all in advance and filtering it out in program code. But if it doesn't come from a database this point is kind of moot.

Comment: The solution from @JonathonChase is o(n), with the current information you gave us there is no better solution. `Sentence.Count(word => Words.Contains(word));` is 2-3 times faster than intersect. Intersect creates a `Set<T>` internally so its not terrible.

Comment: It could be the case that you chose wrong approach before asking the question. What are you trying to do exactly? Your code will run through entire sequences, that's why it takes so long. If you collect with First() you will speed it up, but you will only get first word in common, if you want all words in common, you will need to check entire sentences, hence the time complexity... If latter is the case, you could dump lazy streams and apply some dynamic programming - achieve speed up at the expense of memory. You wouldn't need to enumerate two sentences for each comparison - just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will utilize `HashSet<T>.Contains` method which is more performant. Time complexity of `HashSet<T>.Contains` is O(1).

```cs
public int GetSameWordCount(Sentence sentence)
{
    var count;
    foreach(var word in sentence.Words)
    {
         if(Words.Contains(word))
             count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Note**

If the list of the words is sorted you can use below approach.

```cs
        var enumerator1 = set1.GetEnumerator();
        var enumerator2 = set2.GetEnumerator();
        var count = 0;
        if (enumerator1.MoveNext() && enumerator2.MoveNext())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var value = enumerator1.Current.CompareTo(enumerator2.Current);
                if (value == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (!enumerator1.MoveNext() || !enumerator2.MoveNext())
                        break;
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    if (!enumerator1.MoveNext())
                        break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!enumerator2.MoveNext())
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Confirming manual `count` as fastest answer available.  
Very slightly faster than `.Count(word => Words.Contains(word))`